# Saving to MongoDB using Mongoose fails on ObjectId as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently receiving a validation error when trying to save my object to MongoDB using Mongoose/Joigoose. The basic gist of the schema is that of a simple Group object with a reference to a parent Group's ObjectId (parent_group).

Here's the error:
`ValidationError: parent_group: Validator failed for path 'parent_group' with value '5f32d6c58d0c4a080c48bc79'`

The code for my Group schema definition looks like this:

```js
// Imports (for reference)
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // v5.9.29
const Joigoose = require('joigoose')(mongoose); // v7.1.2
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi'); // v17.1.1
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator'); // v2.0.3
const ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

// Schema
const joiGroupSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    id: Joi.string().required().meta({ _mongoose: { unique: true }}).regex(/^[\w-]+$/).max(50),
    name: Joi.string().required().max(50),
    notes: Joi.string().allow(null),
    parent_group: Joi.string().allow(null).regex(/^[0-9A-Fa-f]*$/).max(24).meta({ _mongoose: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Group' }}),
}).options({stripUnknown: true});

const groupSchema = new mongoose.Schema(Joigoose.convert(joiGroupSchema));
groupSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
const Group = mongoose.model("Group", groupSchema);
```

My mongoose save call looks like this:

```js
// This code is inside of an Express HTTP POST definition (hence the result.value and req/res)
let model = new Group(result.value);
model.save(function (err, doc) {
    // On error
    if (err) {
        if (err.errors.id && err.errors.id.properties.type == 'unique') {
            res.status(409);
            return res.send('POST failed');
        }
        res.status(500);
        return res.send('POST failed');
    }
    res.status(200);
    return res.send('success');
});
```

The data I'm passing using Postman looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "asdf",
    "name": "ASDF",
    "notes": "postman",
    "parent_group": "5f32d6c58d0c4a080c48bc79"
}
```

I've tried different formats of the parent_group string, tried passing it through JS after converting it using `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f32d6c58d0c4a080c48bc79")`, but I keep receiving the same error. I was unable to identify which validator is failing, but that could just be my unfamiliarity with debugging Mongoose.

It is also worth noting:

- the ObjectId is correct
- a null ObjectId works just fine
- the error is being caught in model.save()

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: A ValidationError should be from joi/joigoose.. what is in `error.details`?

Comment: https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#validationerror

Comment: @Matt The error is being caught within model.save(), so unless joi is creating validators for my schema, it appears to be on the mongoose side. The only thing noteworthy is that type & kind in errors.parent_group.properties are "user defined".

Comment: it looks like joigoose adds the [joi validator](https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose/blob/3af65e62774752145daed5d5e27cd74a742cf63a/lib/index.js#L99-L101) but masks the joi [error](https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose/blob/master/lib/index.js#L315-L326). try validating the inbound object against `joiGroupSchema`.

Comment: @Matt That's odd because I'm already validating using joi before doing the Mongoose call, using joiGroupSchema to do so. `let result = joiGroupSchema.validate(req.body); if (result.error) ...` The validated result is what I'm passing into model.save().

Comment: @Matt After looking at the code links you sent, I tried commenting out the `output.validate` assignment in the joigoose index.js and that fixed the issue. I was unaware that joigoose was adding joi validators to mongoose, which is not a functionality I'm needing for my application. My primary reasoning for using joigoose was to consolidate schema definition, not to affect the validation of mongoose. For the time being, I'm going to use that fix and maintain it using patch-package in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason my ObjectId was failing validation is [joigoose adds joi validators to the Mongoose schema behind the scenes](https://github.com/yoitsro/joigoose/blob/3af65e62774752145daed5d5e27cd74a742cf63a/lib/index.js#L99-L101). Without looking into it too deeply, my understanding is that when joi validates the ObjectId as a string, it passes; after Mongoose converts the ObjectId to an object rather than a string (as the joi validator was expecting), that's where the added validator fails.

Since adding joi validators to Mongoose schema is not a functionality that I want (I am just using joigoose to consolidate schemas), as a quick-and-dirty fix, I commented that section out of joigoose directly in my local copy of it. I am currently using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package) to maintain this patch in my application.